# Using Rocksdb to store custom data types?

Tags: c++, rocksdb

I want to write a C++ program using [Rocksdb](http://rocksdb.org/) to store key, value pairs which are not in std::string type. For instance, I want use *int* data-type as the key and values in following data type as the value.

```
typedef struct custom_type {
    int timestamp;
    int count;
    char* path;
} custom_type_t
```

Would you let me know how can I achieve this or recommend me some else choices that I can try for?

Thanks a lot for your help in advance!

Comment: You can transform int and custom_type_t into sequence of bytes, that you can in std::string.

Answer (score 4):

You can serialize your custom data as a string using serialization libraries. You can use a bunch of protocols provided by [Apache Thrift](https://thrift.apache.org/docs/concepts) to seriazlie them to a string and store them to rocksdb.